# How to split WPF control to render in smaller chunks?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, rendering, itemscontrol

The question is: Can I split my DataGrid or ItemsControl to render control in smaller chunks so that UI is not blocked for 15sec to render the whole control?

I actually thought that render is not blocking the UI, because it is made in different thread.

---

My ItemsControl hosts several (up to say 20) datagrids. Some of them can contain up to 100 rows and some are just 1 row short. I'm experiencing heavy lag when I fill underlying ObservableCollection of items.

Here is a brief explanation of what am I trying to do:

1. In UIThread I pick some data.
2. This data is sent to VM
   2.5. VM sets IsBusy flag that makes ItemsControl to change template to a loading placeholder screen.
3. VM makes several DB reqests in BackgroundWorker
4. VM BackgroundWorker Dispatcher.Invokes DataViews back to VM's ObservableCollection one DataView at a time
   Up to this point everything works great: UI is responsible, progressbar updating and so on, but then:
5. VM signals: IsBusy=false => ItemsControl changes it's template back to it's original state
6. The UI **hangs** for ~15sec to render all the DataGrids in ItemsControl (I can see CPU high CPU usage)

Here is some code:

XAML (I've put ItemsControl inside ScrollViewer because I found this is the only way to get content scrollable.):

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
                      VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                      VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
    <ItemsControl 
                  DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource TerminalMaskVM}}"
                  VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                  Style="{StaticResource LoadingControl}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TerminalMaskVM}, Path=TerminalMasks}"
                  x:Name="MaskContainer">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <DockPanel
                    VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                    VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                    IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander IsExpanded="True" Header="{Binding MaskTableName}">
                        <gui:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MaskTable}"
                                      EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
                                      VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                                      VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                         ...columns definitions, etc..
                         ...closing tags here
```

I've made a broad search of the problem and tried the following things:

1. Specified VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" and VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
2. Tried to switch ItemsControl container to DockPanel
3. Set RowHeight and columns Width to a fixed value

All that did not affect rendering time.

Comment: I think that outer scrollviewer take virtualization out of play for contained control (e.g. DataGrid) as they have unlimited height.  When you open a DataGrid do you use the scroll in the datagrid to navigate or the scroll on the outer scrollviewer?  If the answer is the outer then the DataGrid is not virtualizing.

Comment: Scrollviewer takes control of the scrolling. But I have to move mouse pointer to the scrollbar to make it work. If I remove scrollviewer then contents of itemscontrol become unscrollable nomatter what itemcontainer I use.